# Desing Excel and open it as PDF using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created an Excel document using javascript and I open that document but I want it to open/save as PDF not as excel document I have tried many different ways but it didn't work can anyone help.
This is the code that I use.

```js
function exportToExcelPdf() {
  input_box = confirm("Експортирај во Microsoft Excel?");
  if (input_box == true) {
    var xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    var xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    xlBook.worksheets("Sheet1").activate;
    var XlSheet = xlBook.activeSheet;
    XlSheet.Name = "Sheet Name";

    var myRange = XlSheet.Range("A1:L1");
    myRange.merge();
    myRange.value = "Something Some Text";
    myRange.font.size = 14;
    myRange.font.bold = "true";
    myRange.HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
    myRange.interior.colorindex = "37";

    var myRange = XlSheet.Range("A3:L3");
    myRange.merge();
    myRange.value = "Something Some Text";
    myRange.font.size = 11;
    myRange.font.bold = "true";
    myRange.HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
    myRange.interior.colorindex = "37";


    var dt = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');
    for (var y = 1; y < dt.rows.length; y++)
    // detailsTable is the table where the content to be exported is
    {
      for (var x = 0; x < dt.rows(y).cells.length; x++) {
        XlSheet.Cells(y + 18, x + 1) = dt.rows(y).cells(x).innerText;
        XlSheet.Cells(y + 18, x + 1).HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
      }
    }


    //autofit the columns
    XlSheet.columns.autofit;

    xlApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;

    // Make visible:   
    xlApp.visible = true;

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
    CollectGarbage();
    //xlApp.Quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: What javascript library are you using here?

Comment: No library this is the all the code I use and it works for Excel but I don't know how to convert it to PDF

Comment: In which lang? *C#? Javascript?*

Comment: In asp.net (vb.net) / JavaScript
But I need it as javascript code.
To ad something in this code so it can convert it to PDF